# Error handling API fetch request with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, testing, error-handling

I'm using React, and just wanted some advice on error handling.

I have my fetch request in an async function, this function is in another folder and is being imported in my App.js file. Im doing this because I want to try out testing with mock service worker, and have read its easier with the requests in a separate file.

From looking at my code below, is this best practice for error handling? Is there a better way thats more concise?

Here is my fetch async function, at the moment i've purposely gave the wrong env variable name so it will give me a 401 unauthorised error.

```
require('dotenv').config()

export const collect = async () => {
    const key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KE
    try{
      const res = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=${key}`)
      if(res.status !== 200){
          throw new Error(res.status)
      }
        const data = await res.json()
        return data
      } catch (error){
        let err = {
          error: true,
          status: error.message,
        }
        return err
      }
}
```

This is being called in my App.js file (not rendering much at the moment)

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { collect } from './utilities/collect'
require('dotenv').config()

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState("")
  const [error, setError] = useState({ error: false, status: "" })
  const handleFetch = async () => {
      let newData = await collect()
      if(newData.error){
        setError({ error: newData.error, status: newData.status })
      }else {
        setData(newData)
      }
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>weather</h1>
      <button onClick={handleFetch}>fetch</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any help or advise would be great.

Answer (score 2):

When writing an abstraction around **Promises** or  **async** and **await** one should make sure it is used appropriately, that is a good **Promse** must allow it consumer to use it **then** and **catch** method or should allow it consumer use **try** and **catch** to consume it and provide appropriate information on Errors

From Your code, The abstraction doesnt gives back an appropriate response and doesnt follow the standard behavior of a promise it always resolve and never reject and though the code works its implementation of the **collect** is different from a standard **Promise** and wont be nice for a standard code base, for example a good abstraction will provide error information returned from the **third party api**

**Appropriate way to amend code**

The third party api returns this response

```
{
 "cod":401, 
 "message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."}
```

This should be your implementation

```
// Your fetch functon abstraction modified
require('dotenv').config()
const collect = async () => {
    const key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KE;
      const res = await fetch(
        `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=${key}`,
      );
      if (res.status !== 200) {

        const error = await res.json();
        throw {message: error.message,status:error.cod};
      }
      const data = await res.json();
      return data;
  };
```

Your app component should now be like this

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { collect } from './utilities/collect'
require('dotenv').config()

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState("")
  const [error, setError] = useState({ error: false, status: "" })
  const handleFetch = async () => {
      try {
            let newData = await collect()
            setData(newData)
      } catch(e){
          setError({ error: e.message, status: e.status })
      }
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>weather</h1>
      <button onClick={handleFetch}>fetch</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```